# Derivative before Numerical Integration

Tags: functions, numerical-integration, evaluation, argument-patterns

I need to take the derivative of a function that have a numerical integration on it. The variable in which the integration will be taken is not the same as the one in which the derivative will be taken, so I can take the derivative before integrating the expression.
I have tried the following:

```
nfun[x1_?NumericQ, x2_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Cos[x1^x/x2], {x, 2, 3}]
tvar = {x1 -> 0.1, x2 -> 0.3};    
D[nfun[x1, x2], x1] /. tvar
```

And it worked pretty fine. But my real expression has multiple variables and multiple numerical integrations, so I would like to take a list of arguments as input. I also have to take one derivative for each variable. So I tried the following:

```
nfun1[arg : {_?NumericQ ..}] := NIntegrate[Cos[#1^x/#2], {x, 2, 3}] & @@ arg
```

But when I try:

```
D[nfun1[x1, x2], x1] /. tvar
```

It doesn't work...

I have tried what is proposed in here: [Derivative after numerical Integration](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73196/derivative-after-numerical-integration/73208#73208) (2nd answer), but I couldn't get it to work
Do you have any sugestions?

I hope I could express myself correctly

---

Edit: As Mark and Myke showed, the syntax in the second try is wrong, it should be:

```
D[nfun1[{x1, x2}], x1] /. tvar
```

But still not working :(

Comment: without evaluating your stuff one things that stands out is that your second definition is a one argument function that has as its arguments a list. Yet you are trying to take the derivative of a two argument function where the arguments are a sequence

Comment: Try this instead: `nfun1[arg : _?NumericQ ..] := NIntegrate[Cos[#1^x/#2], {x, 2, 3}] &@arg; D[nfun1[x1, x2], x1] /. tvar`. Does that work?

Comment: I used     Inactive[NIntegrate]    , it worked very well :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that your first solution generates a spurious complex part.

```
nfun[x1_?NumericQ, x2_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Cos[x1^x/x2], {x, 2, 3}]
tvar = {x1 -> 0.1, x2 -> 0.3};
D[nfun[x1, x2], x1] /. tvar // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.17, -0.00527135 - 9.7792*10^-9 I}  *)
```

We will also see that it's rather slow to differentiate, too.  This is because *Mathematica* is computing the derivative numerically, which causes the integral to be computed many times.  This integral has a symbolic derivative, which can be used to speed up the calculation of the derivative.

Using `If`is an easy way to get the protection of `NumericQ` but still be able to differentiate the expression.  (**Update:** I did have `ConditionalExpression`, which for some reason was working in my original session, but shouldn't have. It doesn't hold its arguments.)

```
nfun1[arg_List] := If[arg ∈ Reals, NIntegrate[Cos[#1^x/#2], {x, 2, 3}]] & @@ arg
```

There is no spurious imaginary part to the derivative and it is almost 50 times faster, too.  (The `Reals` can be replaced with the `Complexes`.)

```
nfun1[{x1, x2}]
D[%, x1] /. tvar // RepeatedTiming
(*
  If[(x1 | x2) ∈ Reals, NIntegrate[Cos[x1^x/x2], {x, 2, 3}]]
  {0.0045, -0.00527132}
*)
```

**Update:** I had a function `NEval` was considerably faster than the `ConditionalExpression` "solution."   The arguments to `NEval` consisted an expression `expr` to be evaluated when the rest of the arguments are numeric.  There is also a special derivative rule, so that differentiating `NEval` simply differentiates `expr`. While one is naturally initially fond of all one's creations, there seems little need for it in this case.  See edit history, if curious.

Comment: Thank you very much, Michael... I dont know what I am doing wrong, but when I try your code, it gives me the message:    "The integrand Cos[x1^x/x2] has evaluated to non-numerical values for \
all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{2,3}}."

Comment: @Fábio Thanks for letting me know. I wasn't getting that before, but in a new session I do.  I must have changed something.  The update seems to work well, and actually it's just as fast as the cumbersome `NEval` solution, which I removed.  (Let me know if you want it back and I'll put it in.)

Comment: Thank you, Michael, it worked like a charm. It REALLY helped me. Anyway, any clue of why `nfun1[arg : {_?NumericQ ..}]` doesn't work, while `nfun[x1_?NumericQ, x2_?NumericQ]` does?

Comment: I don't know exactly.  You can look at ``Derivative[{1, 0}][nfun1][List[0.1`, 0.3`]] // Trace`` and ``Derivative[1, 0][nfun][0.1`, 0.3`] // Trace`` and see that it just doesn't seem to try to do the numeric derivative when the argument to `Derivative` is a `List` (the case ``Derivative[{1, 0}]``).  I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work.  Report it to Wolfram support and see what they say. -- BTW, the numeric derivative is both slower and less accurate, so in a way you're lucky it didn't work. :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your second expression is two-fold. First, to match your syntax, you need to evaluate

```
D[nfun1[{x1, x2}], x1] /. tvar
```

instead. Second, that still doesn't work, for this reason. With your expression,

```
D[nfun1[{x1, x2}], x1]
```

evaluates to

```
Derivative[{1,0}][nfun1][{x1,x2}]
```

and

```
D[nfun1[{x1, x2}], x1] /. tvar
(* Derivative[{1,0}][nfun1][{0.1, 0.3}] *)
```

which I *think* suggests what's going wrong, although I haven't exactly tracked down why that doesn't work.

In any case, this seems to work:

```
Clear[nfun1]
nfun1[arg : _?NumericQ ..] := NIntegrate[Cos[#1^x/#2], {x, 2, 3}] &@arg
tvar = {x1 -> 0.1, x2 -> 0.3};
D[nfun1[x1, x2], x1]
% /. tvar
(* Derivative[1,0][nfun1][0.1, 0.3] *)
(* -0.00527135-9.7792*10^-9 I *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention, march... I missed the syntax thing, but i had already tried that way... Your way works fine, and I may use that, but I would like my function to take a list as argument...